# シェルスクリプト　if分岐でtrueを受け取った場合warning表示して終了する処理の作成

Tags: shellscript

hogeファイルの中身に対して確認処理をおこない、処理を終了するかしないかの判断をしたいです。

・作成したい確認処理の手順

1. hogeファイルの22-24行目の先頭行に#が先頭についているかいないかの判断

   - 先頭に#がある場合はtrue
   - #がなければfalse（この場合は手順2へ進む）
2. 次に各グループのIDに重複があるかの確認（下記のhogeの24行目にあるcccccグループにt44444の重複がある）

   - 追加するIDがあればtrue  なければfalse
   - 重複しているIDあればtrue  なければfalse

手順1.2でfalseだった場合の終了処理をfooファイルに作りたい。
fooファイルは手順1の確認処理しかできていない状態です。
1.2の結果をbooleanで受け取って　warning終了になるif分岐を作成したいです。
合わせて手順２の処理のアドバイスもいただけると幸いです！！

対象のhogeファイルの中身

```
#グループ名 = ID,ID,ID.....とみなします
22行目# aaaaa = txxxxx,txxxxx
23行目bbbbb = t11111,t22222
24行目cccccc = t44444,t55555,t44444
```

確認処理を実行するfooファイルの中身

```
aaaaa=$(cat hoge | head -22 | tail-1)
bbbbb=$(cat hoge | head -23 | tail-1)
ccccc=$(cat hoge | head -24 | tail-1)

#行の先頭に#があるか、ないかの判断
if ["`echo $aaaaa | grep ^#`"]; then
  echo 'ある'
else
  echo 'ない'
fi

if ["`echo $bbbbb | grep ^#`"]; then
  echo 'ある'
else
  echo 'ない'
fi

if ["`echo $ccccc | grep ^#`"]; then
  echo 'ある'
else
  echo 'ない'
fi
```

現在のfooファイルの処理は行先頭に#がある、ないの判断だけです。

----下記「実現させたい処理」----

1. 先頭に＃があるか、ないかの結果をbooleanで受け取る

   - 先頭に＃があるならwarningを表示して処理を終了
2. 各グループに重複したIDかあるか、ないかをtrue,falseで出力(例として現在はcccccグループにt44444のID重複が確認できる)その結果をbooleanで受け取る

   - 重複がなければ(falseの場合)warningを表示して処理を終了

1.2の結果をbooleanで受け取ってwarning終了パターンがtrueになるif分岐を作る
→その中で上記のwarning,exitを行う
→後続処理を続けるパターンについてはここでは何もしない(処理を続けてはいけないwarningパターンをキャッチするだけ)

以上となります。
アドバイスいただけますと幸いです！
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: supaさん有り難うございます！　　１点確認させていただきたいのですが [syntax error near unexpected token `<'] エラーが出てしまいます。。

Answer (score 0):

> ----下記「実現させたい処理」----
>
> 1. 先頭に＃があるか、ないかの結果をbooleanで受け取る
>
>    - 先頭に＃があるならwarningを表示して処理を終了
> 2. 各グループに重複したIDかあるか、ないかをtrue,falseで出力(例として現在はcccccグループにt44444のID重複が確認できる)その結果をbooleanで受け取る
>
>    - 重複がなければ(falseの場合)warningを表示して処理を終了

以下のスクリプトでは bash 特有の機能を利用しています。

- mapfile: read lines from the standard input into the indexed array
  [Bash mapfile builtin command help and examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/mapfile.htm)
- `=~`: pattern matching

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)). The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.

- `${l/#*=/}`: pattern substitution

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`. The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion, Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t arr < <(sed -n '22,24p' data.txt)

for l in "${arr[@]}"
do
  [[ "$l" =~ ^# ]] &&
    {
      printf "'#' is found at beginning of '$l'\n" >&2
      continue
    }

  echo ${l/#*=/} | tr , '\n' | sort | uniq -d 2>/dev/null | grep -Eq '.' ||
    {
      printf "None duplication in '$l'.\n" >&2
      continue
    }

  printf "Passed: '$l'\n"

done

# 実行結果
'#' is found at beginning of '# aaaaa = txxxxx,txxxxx'
None duplication in 'bbbbb = t11111,t22222'.
Passed: 'cccccc = t44444,t55555,t44444'
```